# Weapon manifestations?

Tags: rakudai-kishi-no-cavalry

How are weapons manifested? Are they magic? Are they physical and stored somewhere? I don't quite get how this process works.

It seems like they are embodiments of the user's personality but at the same time they don't look like they need magical power unless they use certain techniques.

The long and short of my question is. What are the weapons in this series? And how are they manifested?

Comment: Can anyone provide a link as well? It'd be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weapons are a physical manifestation of the user's soul. Hence why no two weapons are the same. If the weapon is damaged or broken the user receives damage like what they would if the attack hit they're body.

Comment: Sounds too close to Bleach. I would suggest you add sources to support your answer in order it to be accepted.

Comment: Is that said somewhere in the anime or light novel? Can you site a reference for me to read? I just rewatched the series and I never saw a formal statement.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the weapons that they use are manifestations of their soul's power. They require a minimal amount of magic to actually manifest, but more if you want to do anything more than cut, bludgeon, or, in the case of Illusory form, drain energy.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Is that said somewhere in the anime or light novel? Can you site a reference for me to read? I just rewatched the series and I never saw a formal statement.